# Symfony / Formbuilder. Select a specific field on a querybuilder

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

how can I select a specific field on a querybuilder in a form on symfony?

I'm triying to do this:

```
        ->add('tienda', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AdminBundle:MyTable',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('select tienda')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->orderBy('u.tienda', 'ASC');
            },
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `choice_label` option for it

```
    ->add('tienda', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AdminBundle:MyTable',
        'choice_label' => 'xxx',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->distinct()
                ->orderBy('u.tienda', 'ASC');
        },
        'required' => false,
    ))
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

Comment: Not working.
When we add select('u.xxx') in the query It will work.
But when I'm using this same query with select an error came up "Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string give"
Please help!